# MySQL Change Length of Key

Tags: mysql

Simple question. If I have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `exampletable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `textfield` varchar(700) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `textfield` (`textfield`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How do I change the length of the `textfield` KEY? For `latin1` charset the default length is 767, and for UTF8 it's 255. But if I have a `latin1` table, for example, how do I alter the key to force a max length of 255?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index on the leading part of a `VARCHAR(x)` column.  See here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_textfield ON example_table (textfield(10));
```

This will help with searches. But it's not useful as a primary key or with `GROUP BY`.

You can also include this in a table definition  like so:

```
CREATE TABLE exampletable (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  textfield varchar(700) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY partial_textfield (textfield(10))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <col_name> VARCHAR(255);
```

Be sure you don't have more than 255 character

Comment: As I understand from your post, it's not possible to change the length of the key without changing the length of the column itself?

Comment: No.  the check for the length is on the column ... the key is "derived" from the column ...